# Cual es la jerarquía (IMPORTANCIA) en un conjunto de if anidados?

Tags: c, algoritmos

Realizo esta pregunta con la intención de comprender mas afondo el funcionamiento de los if anidados, lo que quiero saber es que si en un conjunto de X cantidad de if anidados, que sentencia seria la mas importante, que sentencias serian las segundas en importancia en la jerarquía y cuales serian las ultimas en importancias en la jerarquía pondre por ejemplo un código en C++ cuyo fin es encontrar el máximo de 3 numeros, aun que si me pueden brindar una explicación con otro ejemplo y que tenga mas ifs anidados lo agradecería aun mas

```
int x,y,z;
int max,min;

printf("Introduce el valor para x: ");
scanf("%i",&x);
printf("Introduce el valor para y: ");
scanf("%i",&y);
printf("Introduce el valor para z: ");
scanf("%i",&z);

if(x>y){
    if(x>z){
        max = x;
    }
    else{
        max = z;
    }
}
else{
    if(y>z){
        max = y;
    }
    else{
        max = z;
    }
}
printf("El mayor de los tres numeros es: %i\n\n",max);
```

Answer (score 1):

No sé exactamente a que llamas importancia, subo un extracto de un código para el tratamiento de fechas para explicar.

```
int es_Fecha_Valida(tFecha F)
{
    if(F.anio>1600)
        if(F.mes >01 && F.mes<=12)
            if(F.dia>=1 && F.dia<=cant_dias(F.mes, F.anio))
                return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

La "importancia" sí es que entendemos lo mismo, esta dada por el IF que se encuentra en el nivel mayor.
En el código anterior, sí el año es menor o igual a 1600, es decir la condición contraria a la del IF de "primer nivel", los IFs de los niveles inferiores ya no serán evaluados.

Otro ejemplo podría ser:

```
if(a>b)
{
    if(a>c)
    {
        do...
    }
    else if(a>d)
    {
        do...
    }
    else if(a>e)
    {
        do...
    }
}
```

Los IFs que están en el mismo nivel pueden no ser evaluados sí anteriormente se cumplió otro IF del mismo nivel.
Es decir sí el IF a>c da verdadero, los IF que corresponden a a>d y a>e no se evaluarán al tener antepuesto un else.
Cualquier otra duda, comenta!

Comment: Si, eso de "importancia" debe definirse bien. En realidad  en un código correcto si cualquier sentencia se omite el resultado ya no será el mismo. En el ejemplo de las fechas todos los ifs son igual de importantes independendientemente de su nivel de anidamiento e incluso viendo esto es posible que alguien modificará para convertir en un solo if.